# INSERT INTO not working for 2nd table

Tags: php, insert-into, mysql-insert-id

I'm new to PHP but normally able to solve most problems but this one has got me.

I'm trying to create a newsletter sign up (single field) with a single submit button. I have this working fine, sending out an email and inserting the form data into my table. However I want to add functionality to have a confirmation email send to the person who signs up. I've done extensive research and I know the method behind this but my code just is not inputting data into my 2nd table used to store the confirmation information.

I have 2 tables:
Table 1 named 'newsletter' columns are:

```
idmail,emailaddress,datetime,state
```

`idmail` is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Table 2 named 'confirm' columns are:

```
idconfirm,emailaddress,confirmkey
```

Here is my code (I've omitted the email part which goes after this as that all work OK):

```
//connect to database
include('admin/connection.php');
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['email']);
//check if value exists in table
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT emailaddress FROM newsletter WHERE emailaddress = '$email'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) {

//Insert value into database
$query1 = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO newsletter(emailaddress, datetime, state) VALUES('$email','$now','0')");
mysqli_query($dbc, $query1);

// Get ID of last record
$id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc); 

//Create a random key
$hash = $email.date('mY');
$hash = md5($hash);
//Insert value into database
$query2 = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO confrim(idconfirm, emailaddress, confirmkey) VALUES('$id','$email','$hash')");
mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
```

When I submit an email address, the first table is populated correctly.

The goal here is to get the auto ID created in the first INSERT INTO query into a variable then to add that in the 2nd tables column named 'idconfim'.

I tried:

```
echo $id;
echo $email;
echo $hash;
```

and all of the variables hold the correct information.

Does anyone have any ideas? 
I've tried to many things to list here, but I've researched this and I just don't know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all: `INSERT INTO confrim` -> `INSERT INTO confirm`

Comment: Run the query directly on phpmyadmin and see the  message.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Is it just a ___Spolling Irror___ `INSERT INTO **confrim**`

Comment: You are not checking any of the mysqli_ functions for errors Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: The problem here is this `$query2 = mysqli_query($dbc,... '$hash')"); mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);` and you should have gotten an error about that. This besides the possible typo for the table name `confrim`. Edit: I'm surprised you didn't catch that @RiggsFolly ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well I guess its official. I am not omnipotent like you previously thought

Comment: @RiggsFolly Merry Xmas buddy ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- But as it happens my birthday is coming up very soon, so maybe I am

Comment: @Fred-ii- Back atcha Good Buddy

Comment: @RiggsFolly *grazie beaucoup!* et bonne fete en avance.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Looking at the OP's code again, that hash doesn't seem password-related, more like a confirmation key to maybe be used in email later on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting my comment as an answer here:

The problem here is this `$query2 = mysqli_query($dbc,... '$hash')"); mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);` and you should have gotten an error about that. This besides the possible typo for the table name `confrim`.

You need to remove `mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);` here and replace it with:

```
if($query2){ echo "Success"; }

else{ echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc);
```

*(Another edit):* You did the same error here:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO newsletter ... '$now','0')");
mysqli_query($dbc, $query1);
```

and needs to be changed to:

```
if($query1){ echo "Success"; }

else{ echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc);
```

---

As stated in comments by RiggsFolly; don't use MD5 to hash passwords, it's no longer safe. A lot of water's run under the bridge in over 30 years.

Use `password_hash()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and a prepared statement.

**Edit:** It looks to me now that after looking at your code again, that you're not trying to save a password, but more as a confirmation key. If that is the case, then you can disregard the password stuff. However, if you do decide to use MD5 to store passwords with in the future, **don't.**

Comment: Typo Confirm. What An Eye. (Y)

Comment: @NanaPartykar Typo for the table "maybe" ;-) yet the use of 2x `mysqli_query()` is indeed another problem and a big one at that.

Comment: Think you are right about the password hash not being a password. Knee jerk reaction.... with the emphasis on _jerk_ of course

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Meh...* no biggie buddy ;-) it was a normal reaction to the mention/their use of MD5; an honest mistake.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems is that you aren't showing the MySQL error, if there is one.  So you need to either check the server logs for the error in PHP, you can force to print the error to the error log or do something else:

for example:

```
mysqli_query($dbc, $query2) or error_log(mysqli_error($dbc));

mysqli_query($dbc, $query2) or custome_error_handler(mysqli_error($dbc));
```

As well php should be returning an HTTP error to the client.  You should be catching that error.

Once you see the SQL error it will be easy to figure out what you did wrong.

**EDIT** Fred ii caught the real error, but I think the error would have been thrown the first time the mistake is made:

```
mysqli_query($dbc, $query1);
```

`$query1` isn't a string.  And if you noticed you already executed the query on the line above.  Reading the PHP error logs will show you exactly where the error is.

Comment: "I think" isn't much of an answer (I think, is more a comment). Look at their code again; I outlined what is wrong but didn't submit an answer, fearing a possible rabbit hole.

Comment: Thats a good point, anyways reading the error logs would have led the programmer to the problem which you just pointed out.

Comment: You are technically correct though, about using `mysqli_error()` which would have clearly thrown them an error.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry for wasting time.

Thanks to jeffery_the_wind for pointing me to the logs. I will use them in future.

The problem was TWO spelling mistakes, one in the column name in the php and one on the mysql database. confrim is not a word! I'm slightly lexdixlick!

Thanks for your prompt responses.

Comment: Um.... it wasn't just that. Did you not see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41186319/1415724 ? I made a few edits to it since my original post. What you gave as an answer here, doesn't really account as an answer for future visitors, IMHO.

Comment: I'm also (truly) dyslexic but that doesn't stop me from making 100% sure that I don't make a mistake.